# Log out automatico no Asp.Net Core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

Estou utilizando identity em um projeto em ASP.NET CORE, porém estou tendo problemas ao fazer upload do projeto em produção.

Ao fazer um POST ele envia minhas informações normalmente, mas ao mudar de página e enviar outro POST ocorre "logout" do sistema. Feito login novamente o POST funciona, porém se mudar de página e tentar fazer um segundo POST ele sai novamente.

O ASP NET CORE vem com "forms" com AntiForgeryToken pré-setado, então todos os métodos de POST já estão decorados com o atributo de [ValidateAntiForgeryToken].

Já tentei diversas maneiras de aumentar a data de expiração dos cookies do identity ou de antiforgery, obtive sucesso na mudança, mas não parou ainda de fazer logout.

OBS: em ambiente de desenvolvimento não ocorre logout em nenhum momento.

Comment: O problema foi resolvido? Onde está o código do seu Controller e Actions?

Comment: Consegui conter o problema por enquanto, ainda sim da uns "logoff" em algum momento se a internet estiver lenta. Mas o problema foi que em meu servidor era necessário montar um aplicativo no IIS para cada subdomínio e eu não estava fazendo isso, fazendo com que o aplicativo do domínio principal rodasse o código. Tinha alugado uma hospedagem nova e não estava acostumado com o cPanel. Hoje publico os sites ASP.NET com dependência no framework e não auto-suficiente também! Você está com o mesmo problema?